# Forming variable dynamically in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a dictionary of items like

```
{'Switch_all': 'N/A', 'Router_down': 'N/A', 'Switch_down': 'N/A', 'Router_all': 'N/A'}
```

And i would like to iterate over this dictionary in the django template by using the key ex :Switch_all.

I am able to get the data from dictionary if i give the key like Switch_all

The problem is that i need to form this variable dynamically from another list. For ex the list will contain the following data

```
['Swich','Router']
```

I have to iterate over this list and append the string like _up, _down to form new variable that is one of the keys in the dictionary.

Now i have tried by using the custom template filters, still i found difficulty in passing two arguments

the code that i included in the template is

```
{{ value|dyndictval:header,"_up" }}
```

in the above code value is the dictionary and header is the variable that takes argument like Switch, Router and when appended with second argument (here it is '_up') would form the key in the dictionary(value).

The custom filter code is

```
def dyndictval(d, key1):
keys = key1.split(',')
return d.get(keys[0]+keys[1],'')
```

I have overcome this requirement by using a seperate variable created using with tag as below and used the same to pass the argument to the custom filter

```
{% with header|add:"_up" as templatevar %}>>>>{{templatevar}}<<<<
                    {{ value|dyndictval:templatevar }}
                    {% endwith %}
```

Comment: This sort of processing should be done in the view; not the template.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried doing it with custom tag still i have some issue in it.                                                                                                i have a method                                                                       def dyndictval(d, key1):
    print 'debug in dyndictval<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<',key1
    return d.get(key1,'')                                               when i tried to call as {{ value|dyndictval:header,"_up" }} from template it failed

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in the view. The template should contain minimal logic only.

Within the view this can be done very easily using python. If you need help post your code as an edit to the question and people will help.

Comment: Hi i have modified the post with changes that i have done. i used custom filter. still it failed as it is not possible to pass more than one aruments.  Any help on this will be useful for me

Comment: I have overcome the issue i faced and  i have edited to post to add the details of what i did to fix it